# Why do we need the <Directory> in Apache .conf file?

Tags: apache, config

Simple question:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName notes.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/notes

    <Directory "/var/www/notes">
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On first sight this works exactly like just putting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName notes.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/notes
</VirtualHost>
```

So why do we need this `<Directory>` statement anyway?

I've found several examples on the web of which some were using the `<Directory>` or `<Proxy>` thing and others were just putting their settings under the `<VirtualHost>` branch.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can define particular parameters for particular directories.

You could do

```
<Directory "/var/www/notes/private">
   Options -Indexes
<Directory>
```

or something similar.  `DocumentRoot` will work by itself, but if you want to add directory options, you'll need to use the Directory tag.